# Get values from dictionary based on condition and display results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of dicts 'players':

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Each dict with the following structure:

```
{name:'John', position:'fwd'}, {name:'Peter', position:'mid'}, {name:'Bill', position:'def'},...
```

---

And I'm extracting an displaying one player name per row, like so:

```
  render() {
    const { players } = this.props;
    if(players){
    return (
     <div className="app">
        <div className="pos-wrapper">
          <div className="row">
            <Row>{players[0].name}</Row>
            <Row>{players[1].name}</Row>
            <Row>{players[2].name}</Row>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <Row{players[3].name}</Row>
            <Row>{players[4].name}</Row>
            <Row>{players[5].name}</Row>
          </div>
            <div className="row">
            <Row>{players[6].name}</Row>
            <Row>{players[7].name}</Row>
            <Row>{players[8].name}</Row>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }else{
    return null}
  }
```

---

Now I need to display only forwards on the first 3 `<Row>` components, mids on the second group, and defenders on the last group of `<Row>`.

---

QUESTION:

How do I create a function in javascript that takes 'position' as an argument and display the first, second and third name for each player, and call this function like so?

```
<Row>call here</Row>
<Row>call here</Row>
<Row>call here</Row>
```

Note: I cannot use `map()`, I must keep the layout structure above.

Comment: No idea what are you asking for. Consider adding some details to your question.

Comment: see if it's clearer now

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use map?

Comment: yes, layout (css) reasons.

Comment: @a2441918 unless you can come up with a map solution that keeps this layout intact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to group them by positions, right?

In this case, you can create a function then `filter()` the array depending on the player's position then `map()` them. To make sure it's just the first 3, then maybe you can also use `slice()`

This shouldn't change the original array.

```js
function getPlayersByPosition(players, position){
  return players.filter((player) => player.position === position).slice(0, 3);
}

const players = [{name: "One", position: "fwd"}, {name: "Two", position: "db"}, {name: "Three", position: "fwd"}];

// React code now
getPlayersByPosition(players, "fwd").map((player) => <Row>{player.name}</Row>)
```

You can use it this way.

```
<div className="row"> 
   {getPlayersByPosition(players, "fwd").map((player) => (
        <Row>{player.name} </Row>
    ))} 
</div>
```

Hopefully this answers your question or at least points you to the right direction!

Comment: I just can't se how to insert `getPlayersByPosition(players, "fwd").map((player) => <Row>{players[0].name}</Row>)`in the structure above.

Comment: Ahh. To do this, you can do

<div className="row">
    {getPlayersByPosition(players, "fwd").map((player) => 
        <Row>{player.name} </Row>
    )}
</div>

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2dxhgs

```js
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

const data = [
  { name: "A", position: "fwd" },
  { name: "B", position: "mid" },
  { name: "C", position: "def" },
  { name: "D", position: "fwd" },
  { name: "E", position: "mid" },
  { name: "F", position: "def" },
  { name: "G", position: "fwd" },
  { name: "H", position: "mid" },
  { name: "I", position: "def" }
];

const dataGroup = {
  fwd: data.filter(item => item.position === "fwd"),
  mid: data.filter(item => item.position === "mid"),
  def: data.filter(item => item.position === "def")
};

const Row = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="pos-wrapper">
        {Object.keys(dataGroup).map(item => (
          <div key={item} className="row">
            {dataGroup[item].map(row => (
                <Row key={row.name}>{row.name}</Row>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: considering the image above, instead of `<div>A</div>`, how can I end up with `<Row>A</Row>` instead? like I said in the question, this solution with `map()` messes with the layout. Row is a component, with css and all, not a <div>

Comment: In my code, Row returns div. In your code, Row can be anything. const Row = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>; See here, as it returns duv

Answer (score 0):

```js
const makeGroup = players => players.reduce((acc, player) => {
  switch (player.position) {
    case 'fwd':
      acc[0].push(player);
      break;
    case 'mid':
      acc[1].push(player);
      break;
    case 'def':
      acc[2].push(player);
      break;
  }
  return acc;
}, [[], [], []])

function App({ players }) {
  const grouped = makeGroup(players);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="pos-wrapper">
        {grouped.map(group => {
          return (
            <div className="row">
              {group.map(player => <Row>{player.name}</Row>)}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```